# Install packages on cygwin

Tags: packages, installing, windows

I use latex for cygwin, installed by the cygwin setup GUI. How can I install other missing package? For example i haven't tikz... I've to manually install it or there is a better solution?

Comment: Predrag mentioned TeX Live in his answer. If cygwin is not important for you, then TeX Live has an easy to use installer for Windows that may be found [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). On Windows [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) is another popular distribution that is actively maintained. Both include TikZ. If at all possible use one of these two.

Comment: The simple answer is 'because it is there'. There are packages in CygWin that depends on tex and a distribution of tex is installed *within CygWin*.
If it is installed there should be a way to update/install new packages in a sane way, full stop.
Alberto wants to know how. And so am I.
Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want LATEX in Cygwin so you can use Bash Script and commands line you may choose to install a complete version of for example Miktex and Texniccenter in Windows
and then create a symbolic link to the .exe files you need to compile (e.g. latex.exe, pdflatex.exe, ...) your .tex file from Cygwin Bash shell:

```
ln -s 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe'  /usr/local/bin/latex
```

Comment: installed MiKTeX and put miktex/bin in the PATH

Comment: This does not work for all installed parts of MiKTeX, cf. [Problem executing script for latexdiff](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104450).

Answer (score 5):

I have not used Cygwin for a long time but the last time I checked the default TeX installation was still teTeX. I do not use tikz so I do not know if it was part of teTeX. In any case if you really want you could try to install TeXLive. In theory that should not be a problem but in practice that is another story. You can definitely use TeXLive in Cygwin from live USB or CD. The real question for me is why do you need Cygwin to use tikz on your Windows machine when you have native MiKTeX package of TeX and friends for Windows as well as TeXLive which in spite of being more geared towards Unix and Unix like system can be easily installed natively? I am guessing that teTeX is needed just as a dependency for some other Cygwin packages which are not natively available for Windows. Now historically speaking installing TeX on Windows for example 10 years ago (before ProTeXt MiKTeX installer) was not actually trivial and Cygwin route was the simplest one.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-cyg install texlive
apt-cyg install texlive-collection-latex
```

You may need install [apt-cyg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286337/how-to-install-apt-cyg-for-cygwin) first.