# Problem executing script for latexdiff

Tags: miktex, windows, scripts, latexdiff, cygwin

I am a *LaTeX beginner and new to Scripting*. I try to implement [this interesting solution for latexdiff and multiple files](https://eothred.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/latexdiff-and-git/) found in [this question-answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/using-latexdiff-with-git/44026#44026) before I begin writing my phd thesis. However using...

- Win7 (64-bit)
- GitHub (Sourcetree, Git version 1.8.0msysgit.0)
- MikTex 2.9
- ActivePerl version 5.16.2.1602
- cygwin

and after researching I do not know how to execute the script and the documentation on the site linked above is "sparsely". Here is what I did so far:

- Latexdiff is installed and successfully tested
- 'latexbatchdiff.sh' is placed in `C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\Github` (added to PATH)
- Repository Path: `C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\Github\Testlab`

My `C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\Github\Testlab\.git\config`-file looks like this:

```
[core]
    bare = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/MYGITHUBACCOUNT/Testlab.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[difftool.latex]
    cmd = latexdiff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[alias]
    ldiff = difftool -t latex
```

There is also an 'install.sh' which is not documented at all, so I tried...

[image: trying install.sh and failing]

So, how does one execute this script on windows? Do I use the Windows CMD or the Cygwin Terminal? I would be really grateful for a beginner-friendly example.

[image: thats how far I got using cygwin]

Comment: the `\r` means that your install.sh has windows/dos line endings and cygwin wants unix style line endings in the scripts, you can use dos2unix install.sh to get it to have the right endings.

Comment: Yes, this helped. Now this is what I get:

`USER@PC /cygdrive/c/Users/USER/Dropbox/Github/Testlab
$ latexdiff-git
-bash: latexdiff-git: Kommando nicht gefunden.` or

`USER@PC /cygdrive/c/Users/USER/Dropbox/Github/Testlab
$ latexbatchdiff.sh
/cygdrive/c/Users/USER/Dropbox/Github/latexbatchdiff.sh: Zeile 5: ldiff: Kommando nicht gefunden.
/cygdrive/c/Users/USER/Dropbox/Github/latexbatchdiff.sh: Zeile 21: ldiff: Kommando nicht gefunden.
You need to setup the script with a diff command.
Please see the README file that came with this script.
`

Comment: er pass I have never actually used latexdiff, but perhaps someone who has could pick it up from here...

Comment: ok, so far I couldn't figure it out. Answers still welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The error here is that you want to use MiKTeX with Cygwin. But you must decide:

Either you use MiKTeX in usual Windows mode or you use Cygwin as Unix wrapper and have then to use TeX Live for Unix *(i.e. **not** the Windows version of TL)*. With TeX Live you do not neede to install a separate Perl distribution (at least not for Tex use), because it comes with an own rudimentary Perl interpreter.